# Problem with NLog / NuGet adding duplicate sections to app.config

Tags: nlog

If I create a console app for example with VS2019, then add NLOG and NLOG.SCHEMA NuGet packages, I configure NLog in app.config and it looks like this:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd" autoReload="true" throwExceptions="true" throwConfigExceptions="true"
internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogToConsoleError="false" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
...
```

My problem is if a new version of Nlog comes out and its updated via NuGet, it insists on adding a fairly empty  section to my app.config. If I don't pick this up then the app will not run because there are two nlog sections.

Is there a way to prevent this? Apart from being more careful and checking after updates? I am thinking of putting the config in a separate file and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is if a new version of Nlog comes out and its updated via NuGet,

This only happens when you update the NLog.Schema package. So you could skip updating that package. The schema package is not used for the behavior of NLog

Comment: Ok.... schema package is used from my point of view just to ensure I have no warnings of any type in my project. Its a shame it doesn't ask if its ok to add a section.